# How to give certain properties to each cell in a uitable using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, properties

For each cell on my uitable I want to code it so that it equals a certain number because I am going to subtract that from the user's total points. I am just not sure how to give each cell a property. As of right now, I have one prototype cell and created my rows using a let statement. Part of the code below shows that when a user clicks one of the cells a popup appears but what I am aiming to do is to subtract x amount of points simultaneously.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

{
    var redeem = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
    var myIndex = 0

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return(redeem.count)
    }


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = redeem[indexPath.row]

        return(cell)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {

        myIndex = indexPath.row

        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController

        self.present(popOverVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }   


 }
```

Comment: Do you know this number before setting up the cells or does it need to be added to the cell after the cell's creation?

Comment: Yes I do know the number, 7, but I have it under 1 prototype cell

Comment: So you want to use the same constant for all your cells having the same prototype cell?

Comment: No, each cell I want a different constant and that is what I was confused on because the way I coded it (just posted above) made one prototype cell and used a let statement to show the 7 rows

Comment: Your code now seems to be correct, what issue are you experiencing? One prototype cell is enough for you, you would only need more prototype cells if you needed several with different UI layouts, which is not the case for you.

Comment: No issues with building; however, the 7 rows I listed I want each one to have a constant associated with it so when the user touches one, it will subtract from the user's total points and in order to do that I have to create a constant for each one I am just not sure how to do that

Comment: You already have that with the `redeem` array, that's why I was asking what is not working for you at the moment.

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you are saying; so, the ["1", "2",...] in my code just print out in the uitableview. I am trying to get the "1" to be worth 120 points so it will subtract from the total points. How would I do that?

Comment: Have a look at my answer and tell me if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, this is how you can associate a dataset with your tableView cells other than the one you use as a datasource.
You just have to store the "points" associated with each tableview cell in another data structure. At the moment another array seems sufficient.

In `didSelectRowAt` you just substract the points corresponding to your currently selected row from the total points.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    var redeem = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
    var points = [120,55,78,45,8,4,86] //change this to whatever you need, I just put some random values there
    var myIndex = 0

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return redeem.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = redeem[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        myIndex = indexPath.row
        totalPoints -= points[indexPath.row]

        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController  
        self.present(popOverVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you this was helpful. Now if i wanted to disable the cells because they do not have enough points would this ( if Total_Points >= points ) work since it is an array?

Comment: Glad I could help. Please up vote my answer if you found it useful. What do you mean by disabling the cells? Do you want to hide the cells/make them non-selectable that have a point bigger than totalPoints?

Comment: So for my app they have to save up points to redeem them and as of right now the code does subtract them but it ends up with negative points which I don't want. In my code I want to say that if the user's total points are greater than or equal to the certain selected cell, then the pop up appears (the popoverVC), but I do not know how to make the if statement

Comment: Just put the `popOverVC` part inside an if statement with the condition `if totalPoints >= points[indexPath.row]`.

Comment: Okay thank you, and for the else statement how would I say do nothing if the Total_Points does not equal to points[indexPath.row]

Comment: Everything you put inside the if statement only gets executed if the condition is evaluated to true, so if you leave the else statement empty, nothing happens. I really encourage you to read the Swift book by Apple, you could benefit from it a lot.

Comment: In iBooks? Thank you I accidentally added a breakpoint so it wasn't working properly and I also up voted your answer; however, it takes 15 reps for it to actually display

Comment: Yes, it is accessible through iBooks. Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You have create an `UITableViewCell` subclass.

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var myVar: Int = 123
}
```

If you're using Interface Builder then set the class of your cell and on your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you cast the cell as your type an operate with that variable, something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell("identifier", at: indexPath) as? MyCustomCell else {
        return UITableViewCell
    }

    print(cell.myVar)

    return cell
}
```

You must know that you shouldn't use the cell itself to **store** the value because of the reuse of the cells. Your data source must hold those values.

Assuming what you stated in your question I imagined something like:

**WARNING: Untested code**

```
class MyVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    private var dataSource = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    private var userPoints = 10

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell("identifier", at: indexPath) else {
            return UITableViewCell
        }

        let diff = dataSource[indexPath.row] - userPoints
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(diff)"

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: I posted my code above. In the UI properties for the uitableview I selected one prototype cell and had multiple rows by using a let statement. Some of the code above deals with the function of a cell when selected and I coded it on another class. Now my question is if I am suppose to create 7 prototype cells and then function it? If so, what steps do I have to take?